# R applying function on a dataframe

Tags: r, apply

I am trying to apply this function:

```
if.class <- function(data){
  as.data.frame(
  if (data == '[1, 4)')   '1'
  else if (data == '[4, 6)')  '2'
  else '3'
)
}
```

on a entire data frame in order to transform the factor levels [1, 4) and [4, 6) to 1 or 2 or 3.
The dataframe looks like this:

```
> dim(mnm.predict.test.class)
  [1] 5750    1
  > head(mnm.predict.test.class)
   predict(mnm, newdata = testing.logist, type = "class")
  1                                                 [1, 4)
  2                                                 [1, 4)
  3                                                 [1, 4)
  4                                                 [1, 4)
  5                                                 [1, 4)
  6                                                 [1, 4)
```

I am using this line for the transformation:

```
 mnm.predict.test.class.factors <- apply(mnm.predict.test.class,c(1,2),if.class)
```

However, the results is weird:

```
 head(mnm.predict.test.class.factors)
 predict(mnm, newdata = testing.logist, type = "class")
 [1,] List,1                                                
 [2,] List,1                                                
 [3,] List,1                                                
 [4,] List,1                                                
 [5,] List,1                                                
 [6,] List,1
```

any ideas why the transformation is not working as expected ?

Comment: what about apply(mnm.predict.test.class,1,if.class) ?

Comment: First of all, being a member for 8 months having asked 22 questions and having accepted/upvoted none is a very bad ratio. You probably don't know how to do it but people have told you in previous questions which you ignored... Anyway have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and please understand how to accept answers. Only accept answers that have solved your problem and know that accepting answers is not compulsory but it is encouraged as it helps people with the same problems find a solution. In general, click the green tick next to an answer to mark it accepted.

Comment: Your function returns a `data.frame` (which is a `list`) for each row. These are then combined to a matrix by `apply`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apply` returns an `array` and thus your output. Convert it to a `data.frame` and you ll be fine:

```
#example data
df <- data.frame(a=rep('[1, 4)',50) )

> df
        a
1  [1, 4)
2  [1, 4)
3  [1, 4)
4  [1, 4)
5  [1, 4)
6  [1, 4)
7  [1, 4)
8  [1, 4)
9  [1, 4)

#just use your function as you used it but wrapped inside a data.frame function
df2 <-  data.frame(apply(df,c(1,2),if.class))

> df2
   a
1  1
2  1
3  1
4  1
5  1
6  1
7  1
8  1
9  1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `levels` function to alter the levels of a `factor`. For example, if you have the factor variable `foo`

```
foo <- factor(
  rep(c("[1, 4)","[4, 6)","[6, 7)","[7, 9)"),2))
R> foo
[1] [1, 4) [4, 6) [6, 7) [7, 9) [1, 4) [4, 6) [6, 7) [7, 9)
Levels: [1, 4) [4, 6) [6, 7) [7, 9)
```

you can change the levels like this

```
levels(foo) <- c("1","2","3","3")
R> foo
[1] 1 2 3 3 1 2 3 3
Levels: 1 2 3
```

In your case, you have a 1 column `data.frame`, so it would be something like

```
Df <- data.frame(
  foo = factor(
    rep(c("[1, 4)","[4, 6)",
          "[6, 7)","[7, 9)"),2)))
##
levels(Df[,1]) <- c("1","2","3","3")
R> str(Df)
'data.frame':   8 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ foo: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 2 3 3 1 2 3 3
```

---

And just as a side note, judging by the output of `head(mnm.predict.test.class.factors)` in your question, it looks like your one column has the unwieldy name `predict(mnm, newdata = testing.logist, type = "class")` - you might want to change this to something more reasonable to type (`names(mnm.predict.test.class.factors)[1] <- "myVar"` for example).